How to set up Bun to compile and bundle the TypeScript files in a directory
I have a project that I need to use Bun to bundle up the TypeScript of the web page. I don't know if I should bundle the HTML pages or the TypeScript files.
Here are my bun.js settings:
import html from 'bun-plugin-html';

await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./public/page1.html', './public/page2.html', './public/page3.html'],
  sourcemap: "inline",
  outdir: './public',
  plugins: [
    html()
  ],
});

The problem with the above is that the HTML pages are overwritten. In each page is the script:
<script type="module" src="index.ts">

When I run bun run start that web page changes that line to point to the JavaScript file:
<script type="module" src="index.js">

I'd like to keep everything in the same directory. I could rename the public directory to source and then export to public but then, what I'm trying to do is bundle the TypeScript files themselves and I could leave the HTML pages alone if that makes sense.
So could I point to the TypeScript files in those HTML pages and then created the bundled JavaScript files? Does that make sense?
Here is my bun.js settings:
// point to typescript files and leave the html pages out of it

await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./public/page1.ts', './public/page2.ts', './public/page3.ts'],
  sourcemap: "inline",
  outdir: './public',
});

Is that possible?

Here's what I found for building all Typescript or Typescript in HTML files in a directory

Install bun (https://bun.sh/docs/installation)
open a folder or project in vscode
open a terminal in your project
call bun add -d bun-plugin-html if you want to bundle typescript in html pages
optionally import other existing modules with bun install (or npm install)
create bun.build.js with the contents below
call bun bun.build.js to build and bundle the typescript (See contents of bun.build.js file)

Your typescript classes will be compiled into a javascript file that bundles all of your typescript. (See https://bun.sh/)
bun.build.js:

// note: you could also pass in one or all of the HTML files
// but if you do that the HTML file might be over written
// to fix that, set an output directory in the options 

import html from 'bun-plugin-html';
import { Glob } from "bun";

// read in all the typescript files in the /public directory
// (or the directory where your typescript files are located)
// and compile them into builded javascript files in the same directory
// using the same name as the typescript file but with a js extension
// your HTML pages should reference the javascript file 
// unless you are compiling the HTML files

const sourceDirectory = "./public/";
const glob = new Glob('*.ts');
var entrypoints = [...glob.scanSync(sourceDirectory)];
entrypoints = entrypoints.map((x) => sourceDirectory + x);
console.log("Compiling " + entrypoints.length + " typescript files...");

const results = await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: entrypoints,
  publicPath: "",
  sourcemap: "inline",
  outdir: './',
  plugins: [
    html()
  ],
});

if (results.success==false) {
  console.error("Build failed");
  for (const message of results.logs) {
    console.error(message);
  }
}
else {
  console.log("Compiled " + results.outputs.length + " javascript files...");
}


I'm the creator of bun-plugin-html. If you want only to compile the TypeScript files, while having a single directory, I would recommend not using bun-plugin-html, and doing what you have shown.
This will still ultimately generate javascript files, such as ./public/page1.js, which will require the HTML to be changed to point to ./public/page1.js instead of ./public/page1.ts. So there isn't much of a point in doing so.
I honestly would just create a directory called src, and do it the recommended bun-plugin-html way, by outputting to a public directory. This enables some convenient features like inlining all javascript and CSS into a single file. But each project has its own need.

Thank you Bjorn. I really like the HTML plugin. On one project I cannot change the output directory so I have added the following workaround (listed as another answer here).

You mentioned that the plugin can inline Javascript and CSS. Can it inline other HTML? I have a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78760797/can-bun-import-an-html-page-or-external-text-file

Do you have a link to read more about the Bun HTML plugin?

You can see all the documentation here. Additionally, there are many different examples, in the form of tests as seen here. I would recommend giving that a once-over. There was a pull request a while back to make it possible to inline HTML, inside HTML, but that had an unresolved issue. I might implement it later in the future. Look at this fork, and it has that feature implemented (do note that it isn't my fork).
