Can Bun import an HTML page or external text file?
I would like to reuse an HTML dialog across pages and I'm having trouble doing that. Can Bun import an HTML page / HTML code that I can then reuse?
Example,
import page from "mypage.html"

I am using Bun to compile Typescript to Javascript on the client side. I am not using Bun as a server.

Yes it is possible. How is impossible to answer because the question is to broad.

@t.niese it's not too broad. I don't know how to do it. do I do it with an import? do i use other methods?

If you just want to read a HTML file. you shouldn't import the file but use the fs package to read the file. import is used for including javascript files (and sometimes as a hack for loading resources in frontend frameworks)

@Evert I'm using bun for bundling on the client side not server side

Then you can use fetch() to load arbitrary files

@Evert good idea. That is a good fall back if there is no native method. Was hoping Bun had a import feature like nodejs and typescript have feature to load json using es module import syntax.

Node.js and typescript also don't do this. This is not a feature of those engines. Some bundlers might. Is your goal to save a http request for this?

If so the easiest might be to wrap your HTML file in a Javascript string!

@Evert I need to have the HTML ready immediately. Using a fetch call does not do this. I want to create HTML templates in external files and reuse them. I have made an answer showing how to do it with an iframe but the iframe takes time to load. It is also not straight forward.

Here is where I use an iframe to accomplish getting an external HTML page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78760720/how-to-reuse-an-html-dialog-element-across-pages

Nothing will be ready immediately, because everything you're describing requires some request to be made. If an iframe serves your needs well enough, the fetch() option should be even better. That said if you want it be part of your bundle, why not wrap your HTML file in a javascript file and include that javascript file?

@Evert I don't have that option. The HTML page will be developed separately as an HTML page or HTML content

Write a script that reads this file and puts it in a .js file that you include.

I found on an answer in the docs.

To import a .html file in Bun as a text file, use the type: "text"
attribute in the import statement.

import html from "./file.html" with { type: "text" };

console.log(html); // <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

https://bun.sh/guides/runtime/import-html
